# Hibernate returns wrong results after updating rows

Tags: java, hibernate

I am still a newbie with Hibernate but I am getting crazy. The thing is that after updating some Entities in the database Hibernate is not able to return me those changes. Also making SQL Queries return old values (Compared with the results I get from MySQLWorkbench)

I thought that it was a Cache problem, however in my hibernate.cnf,xml I have the following lines disabling 2nd line cache. Has anybody a solution for that problem?. I am using Hibernate  v.4.3.1.

The conf file looks like:

```
    <property name="connection.pool_size">3</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">false</property>
    <property name="show_comments">false</property>
```

I have a class to open the session factory:
    public class HibernateUtil {

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    sessionFactory.getCache().evictAllRegions();
    sessionFactory.getCache().evictEntityRegions();
    sessionFactory.getCache().evictCollectionRegions();
    sessionFactory.getCache().evictQueryRegions();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

I am using GWT+RequestFactory+Hibernate the thing is that changing the RequestProxy EntityProxy to ValueProxy (as I dont need an EntityProxy) is working fine. Could it be a problem of RequestFactory?

Comment: Where is the code that actually writes the entities to the DB? Have you committed the transaction?

Comment: Yes I have commited the transaction. In fact if I insert directly a row into a table by MysqlWorkbench Hibernate is not able to refresh it.

Comment: I have changed the connection pool (I was using builtin pool) and it seems to work fine now. What code do you need? An insert into a table?